# Python Client/server code - not able to connect between two machines via ethernet

Tags: python-2.7, client

I am trying to send data (sensor readings, as they are taken) from a Raspberry Pi to my windows laptop using an Ethernet cable, although first I am simply attempting to successfully connect the two machines.

I have created a client.py code and a server.py code. The server is being run on the Pi, and the client is being run on my laptop. I have also setup a static IP address on the Rasperry Pi (192.168.0.17). The Ethernet IP address of the laptop is 192.168.0.16, when I run IPCONFIG on the laptop.

When I run both the server and client code on the raspberry pi (using 'localhost' instead of the static IP) the connection succeeds and I am able to send data, however when I try to communicate with the laptop using the Pi's static IP in the server code, and the same static IP address in the client code on the laptop, the server listens but never receives a connection from the laptop, and the client code on the laptop timesout with the following error:

[Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

This is the first client/server I have attempted to create, therefore my knowledge is very limited and any help would be greatly appreciated. The code in it's current form is posted below, thanks.

Client code:

```
import socket

TCP_IP = '192.168.0.17'
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 20
MESSAGE = "Hello, World!"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

for i in range(0,1000):
    s.send(MESSAGE)
    data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
s.close()

print 'received data:'
```

Server code:

```
import socket
from thread import *

IP = "192.168.0.17"

print IP

PORT = input("Enter the PORT number (1 - 10,000)") #input same port number as client (5005)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

print "Socket created"

s.bind((IP, PORT))

s.listen(10)

print "sock now listening"

while True:
    connection, addr = s.accept()
    print "conn established"
    connection.send("Welcome to the server.")
    while True:
        data = connection.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        connection.sendall(data)
        print data
        connection.close()
s.close()
```

Comment: It is not recommended to publish your IP address

Answer (score -1):

I do not write well in English, but I try. Try the following:
In server code -> s.bind (('', PORT)), thus allowing you to receive connections from any IP.
Luck